# UICollectionViewController How to resize Cell?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm getting a headache by searching how to resize a cell (width and height) in an `UICollectionViewController`.  With an `UITableViewController` there is the method :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But with `UICollectionViewController` I cannot find the method to do it programmatically.

I have an `UICollectionViewCell` but it is not there apparently.

How can I change the size of a cell in a `UICollectionViewController`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need to use a UICollectionViewFlowLayout and the UICollectionViewFLowLayoutDelegate and implement

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Check out the Ray Wenderlich Tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Comment: Unfortunately, this method is called [before the cell is created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750428/resize-uicollectionview-cells-after-their-data-has-been-set). So, it doesn’t work if you need to resize the cell based on varying content size.

Comment: Is there anyway to size cell based on the contents without doing tedious manual coding??

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do it completely automatically, but you can still get the benefit of auto layout. Here's an article with one way: http://blog.amyworrall.com/post/66085151655/using-auto-layout-to-calculate-table-cell-height